# Req.body not available in multer.diskStorage(). Error Property body doesn't exist on type 'Request'

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am trying to save files to local storage using Multer and what I want to do is specify the file name based on the fields in req.body.

Basically, the filename should be something like contractorId-projctId. But VS Code shows the error that body property is not defined on req and when I send the file it saves it as undefined-undefined.png. Here is a screenshot of my code. I've added this screen shot to highlight the fact that VS Code is screaming about req.body.

[image: 1]]

Here is the code for uploadFiles.js

```js
// @ts-check
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import router from './routes/router';

const app = express();

// Setting up middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '15mb' }));


// Setting up routes
app.use('/', router);

// Error handling
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    code: 404,
    error: 'Not found',
    msg: "The resource you're looking for doesn't exist",
  });
});

export default app;
```

I've searched the stack overflow for similar questions but the most question are related to file uploads. The file is being uploaded just fine and I've tested that req.body is also fine, by sending a response back to postman. Here is the request.

[image: screenshot of postman]

Here is my code in router.js.

```js
// @ts-check
import Router from 'express';
import upload from '../configs/filesUploads';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ Okay: true });
});

router.post('/uploads', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({
        error: err,
      });
    } else {
      console.log(req.file);
      res.json({ test: 'Meh', body: req.body });
    }
  });
});
export default router;
```

Here is app.js

```js
// @ts-check
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import router from './routes/router';

const app = express();

// Setting up middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '15mb' }));


// Setting up routes
app.use('/', router);

// Error handling
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    code: 404,
    error: 'Not found',
    msg: "The resource you're looking for doesn't exist",
  });
});

export default app;
```

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshot, paste is as code :)

Comment: You're right. But I wanted to stress the fact that VS code is also screaming about it. I've also edited my question to post all the code.

Answer (score 5):

From [multer documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage):

> Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
>   on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

Try to rearrange your POST body fields by putting `projectId` and `contractorId` first, and the file upload at the end.

Comment: That might be but I doubt that. If you kindly take look at the screenshot of the code, you'll notice that VS Code is already complaining that body field does not exist on request. Please note that I'm also using body-parser. But the error is still there?

Comment: @AdnanAkbar I don't know what to tell you more, I have perfect access to req.body variables in multer's "filename" function using what I told you and `bodyParser.json()`, `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
}));`

Comment: although your suggested method did work, I am not sure why VS Code is complaining about req.body. In this case, I'll be writing the front end as well, so I'll make sure to pass req.body information first, but what if I were to expose this API publically? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @aaKhan Documentation available around seems like it isn't possible. See, for example: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/322. Your best shot would most likely be to tell people in which order the fields should be, and to return an error if any of the parameters you want isn't present in body. Providing a public API should be aimed at somewhat experienced users, which means telling them to reorder their POST fields shouldn't be a problem.