# Problem to change request from get to post and change destination of upload file dynamic in multer nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer

Hey i work with multer package in node js to upload file.

I make it dynamic but the request is in get and i have problem to change it to post.

Its only work to me in get request.

What it doing now?
It save the file in new folder that call flow and take the id from the client.
I need to replace it to post and get the id in post but i want to move the logic to the route and make it stay same. thanks

My Code:

fileupload service:

```
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const models = require("../models");
const fsex = require("fs-extra");
const today = new Date();
const date =
  today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    let flowID = req.params.flowID;
    let path = `./uploads/flow/${flowID}`;
    fsex.mkdirsSync(path);
    callback(null, path);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(8, (err, raw) => {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      cb(
        null,
        date + "_" + raw.toString("hex") + "_" + path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("upload");


module.exports = {
  upload: upload,
};
```

my route:

```
router.get("/uploadfile/:flowID", upload, (req, res, next) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const flowID = req.params.flowID;
  if (!file) {
    const error = new Error("Please upload a file");
    error.httpStatusCode = 400;
    return next(error);
  } else {
    createFileInDB(file.originalname, flowID, file.filename)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("File Created");
        res.json(file);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: `router.post` and pass `flowID` in  body!

Comment: the problem is if you go to the fileupload service i take the flowID in the service and when i change it to body and post it undefiend

Comment: in fileupload service i need the flowID to make new folder with the id and i cant take it in body

Comment: It should look like this `router.post('/uploadfile/, upload, ...)'`. You should send `flowID` through body and access it like this `req.body.flowID`!

Comment: I know this! if you look here is the problem:  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    let flowID = req.params.flowID;
    let path = `./uploads/flow/${flowID}`;

Comment: i cant take the flowID in multer.diskStorage because it separated from the route! only in get its take it

Comment: [Object: null prototype] {} when i console.log(req.body) maybe the problem is postman?

Comment: I found the problem was in postman:
Link to solution:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/54424273/12291697](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54424273/12291697)